# 10 mins countdown timer run continuously for all

Tags: javascript, countdown

I am trying to make a 10 mins countdown timer. That timer should run continuously for everyone. It should not start from the **9.59.59** always.  I tried many ways but was not successful. So I need help.

```
/* return the text name of the day of the week from the day #
*/

function DayNameFromDOW(dDate) {
  var weekday = new Array(7);
  weekday[0] = "Sunday";
  weekday[1] = "Monday";
  weekday[2] = "Tuesday";
  weekday[3] = "Wednesday";
  weekday[4] = "Thursday";
  weekday[5] = "Friday";
  weekday[6] = "Saturday";
  return weekday[dDate.getDay()];
}

function NextWebinarDateandTime() {
  CurDate = new Date();
}

var twoDaysFromNow = new Date().getTime() / 1000 + 86400 * 2 + 1;    
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", () => {
  NextWebinarDateandTime();    

  var CurrentDayOfWeek = CurDate.getDay();
  var CurrentHours = CurDate.getHours();
  var CurrentMinutes = CurDate.getMinutes();
  var CurrentSeconds = CurDate.getSeconds();

  // what's the first hour of day we want to run a webinar?
  FirstHour = 9;
  LastHour = 11;    

  FirstDOW = 1;
  LastDOW = 1;

  /* set the next webinar to the top of the next hour */
  NextWebinar =
    CurDate.getTime() / 1000 +
    (600 - CurrentMinutes * 60) +
    (60 - CurrentSeconds);

  var nSecsUntilNextWebinar =
    800 - CurrentMinutes * 60 + (60 - CurrentSeconds);

  var d = new Date();

  //  d.setTime(n);
  // new Date(CurDate.getTime());
  document.getElementById("CurDate").innerHTML = CurDate;
  document.getElementById("CurDategetTime").innerHTML = d.getTime();

  document.getElementById(
    "nSecsUntilNextWebinar"
  ).innerHTML = nSecsUntilNextWebinar;
  document.getElementById("nextwebinardateandtime").innerHTML = Date(twoDaysFromNow);    

  // Set up FlipDown
  var flipdown = new FlipDown(NextWebinar)

    // Start the countdown
    .start()

    // Do something when the countdown ends
    .ifEnded(() => {});
});
```

Here is my code in codepen :
https://codepen.io/themeix/pen/OJjdwJp

Comment: How is Javascript runing in a browser A supposed to have any effect on any other browsers?  Why would you expect this to be possible?

Comment: My main concern is here. Everyone will see the same time like that, https://codepen.io/smschk/pen/ZEYoaBQ  They made it for 1 hour there and time its same time showing for everyone for the browser refresh

Comment: Count down to a FIXED future point in time, instead of current time + X.

Comment: If i don't use current time then every time i load it will be start from the beginning

Answer (score 1):

You should count down to specific time in future instead of current time + X

Look at this script

```
function getTimeRemaining(endtime){
  const total = Date.parse(endtime) - Date.parse(new Date()); // Convert time variables to miliseconds and substract them.
  const seconds = Math.floor( (total/1000) % 60 );
  const minutes = Math.floor( (total/1000/60) % 60 );
  const hours = Math.floor( (total/(1000*60*60)) % 24 );
  const days = Math.floor( total/(1000*60*60*24) );

  return {
    total,
    days,
    hours,
    minutes,
    seconds
  };
}

const deadline = 'December 31 2021 23:59:59 GMT+0200';
getTimeRemaining(deadline).minutes // You can call your function this way because it return object
```

Comment: How does this address "That timer should run continuously for everyone."?